# Set data for static UITableView cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that looks like this:

[image]

In the first cell I display an `UIImageView` as you can see, there are also 2 labels. Text is set from code. No problem here.

My problem concerns the bottom 4 cells, I woud like to set the data for them dynamically, the When I'm doing this I can't set the labels and the `UIImageView`. I mean setting everything up from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Can someone explain how I can deal with this case?

Comment: Can you please post your code for the "cellForRowAtIndexPath"?

Comment: @ElGuapo - there isn't one for static table views.

Comment: True... I thought the asker was talking about static cells within the cellForRowAtIndexPath method... I figured it was a sectioning issue, but wanted to see more of the code before I answered... good call!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For static tables, you can either create an outlet for each individual cell, or refer to them by indexPath - `[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

By the look of your layout the 4 cells are in section 1, rows 0 - 3.

Once you have a pointer to the cell, you can set its textLabel.text and so on just as you would in cellForRowAtIndexPath in a dynamic table view.